# Mysql could not connect at all

Tags: mysql

Though this question has been asked by few others in this forum I could not resolve the issue

I have installed MySQL 5.6 on Linux RedHat 6

I am able to start the mysql daemon as follows

```
[root@oc3855733574 ~]# /etc/init.d/mysqld start
Starting mysqld:                                           [  OK  ]
```

and I connect from a terminal using 'su - root' by issuing the following command

```
[root@oc3855733574 ~]# mysql -u root -p -h localhost
Enter password: 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

/etc/my.cnf on my system is as follows

```
[client]    ------> Added by me
user=root
password=u8vkdgrv

[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0

# Recommended in standard MySQL setup
sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES 

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

Even I tried with some other user 'mysql -u xxxxx -p' by supplying correct password but nothing worked

Please help me to resolve the issue and I am very new to My SQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are very new with MySQL I recommended to install phpMyAdmin on your server to manage your databases and privileges.

---

**Solution 1 phpMyAdmin:**

Login to your server console using root and run the following commands:

```
rpm -Uvh http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi-release-6.rpm
```

then

```
yum --enablerepo=remi install phpMyAdmin
```

Finally, edit configurations to allow access.

```
nano /etc/httpd/conf.d/phpMyAdmin.conf
```

Search for `127.0.0.1` and replace with your server IP address

Final command restart Apache:

```
service httpd restart
```

Now access phpMyAdmin from browser using root information:

http://serverIP/phpMyAdmin/

---

**Or to fix your issue (restore MySQL password), follow the commands below:**

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
```

then

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysqld stop
```

**Next** we need to start MySQL in safe mode - that is to say, we will start MySQL but skip the user privileges table. Again, note that you will need to have sudo access for these commands so you don't need to worry about any user being able to reset the MySQL root password:

```
sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
```

All we need to do now is to log into MySQL and set the password.

```
mysql -u root
```

**Note:** No password is required at this stage as when we started MySQL we skipped the user privileges table.

**Next** instruct MySQL which database to use:

```
use mysql;
```

Enter the new password for the root user as follows:

```
update user set password=PASSWORD("mynewpassword") where User='root';
```

and finally, flush the privileges:

```
flush privileges;
```

Now the password has been reset, we need to restart MySQL by logging out:

```
quit

sudo /etc/init.d/mysqld stop

sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start
```

Test the new password by logging in:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

You will be prompted for your new password.

Comment: Great stuff!!! It worked like a charm.  However, I'll install 'PHP Admin' for better understanding.  Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Please check "/root/.mysql_secret" file.
root's password is in this file.

like this:

```
sudo cat /root/.mysql_secret
```